# Issue with dynamic Quicklist in Unity

Tags: unity, application-development, launcher, python, quicklists

I would like to add a Quicklist to Gufw app, but it isn't working.
The code is here (you can install reading the INSTALL file):

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gufw-developers/gui-ufw/testing/files/3

I added lines 52-54 to the view (a simple example) from the official API web:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gufw-developers/gui-ufw/testing/view/head:/gufw/view/gufw.py

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI

```
    self.launcher = Unity.LauncherEntry.get_for_desktop_id ("gufw.desktop")
    self.launcher.set_property("progress", 0.42)
    self.launcher.set_property("progress_visible", True)
```

But nothing happen.

But if I run this file with Gufw running:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gufw-developers/gui-ufw/testing/view/head:/gufw/test_launcher.py

```
$ python test_launcher.py
```

The progress bar appears! :/

I don't know what am I missing? :P Any idea? Thanks in advance!

The environment is Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is a bug in Unity, because Gufw is a root app ;)
Created bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1200259
Best regards.